# Reverse Engineering Arturia Microfreak Presets

Tags: synthesizer

Is there any way to see the oscillator, filter, and envelope settings on a given MicroFreak preset? Preferably dumped to a text file?

I want to improve my sound design skills.

Answer (score 4):

The KVR Audio website includes a thread, ["Arturia MicroFreak preset list (in Excel) updated Firmware 2"](https://www.kvraudio.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=539215), which in turn points to a Google Sheet that lists [all the presets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sw2PC3rLdmr5VYoN5v4pXQ0aR077_SZ_xKLOSv4xZF4/edit#gid=1097286090) (not the settings, just a list of presets, updated for v3).

In the spreadsheet, there is a link to a web app called ["MicroFreak Reader"](https://studiocode.dev/doc/microfreak-reader/) (by StudioCode)

> This application allows you to read and display the presets stored in the MicroFreak memory.

> Its main goal is to help visualize and understand how presets are build [sic].

> You don't even have to connect a MicroFreak if you want to browse the free presets packs offered by Arturia because they are already loaded in the application.

—from the MicroFreak Reader site.

As of this post:

> This version does not yet support firmware v3. The support is still incomplete for firmware v2. Updates coming soon...